# TypeScript: number|undefined variable produces string output

Tags: typescript, foreach, undefined, type-safety

In our application we recently faced a hard to find bug, and it turned out that one of our TypeScript `number|undefined` variable strangely produced a `string` output.

I managed to narrow down the a situation and ended up with the following code:

```
  let stringUndef: string | undefined = undefined;
  let numUndef: number | undefined = undefined;

  //Does NOT compile = ✔️
  // stringUndef = "1";

  //Does NOT compile = ✔️
  // if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 0) {
  //   stringUndef = "1";
  // }

  //Does NOT compile = ✔️
  // let intArr1 = [1]  
  // for(var i = 0;i<intArr1.length;i++) { 
  //   stringUndef = "1";
  // }

  //Strangely DO COMPILE = ❗
  //Console Output: "1" - String output from a number|undefined variable = ??
  let intArr2 = [1]  
  intArr2.forEach(function() {
    stringUndef = "1";
  });

  numUndef = stringUndef

  console.log(numUndef)
```

Tried with different TS version at: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Being new to TypeScript my questions are:
Is this the expected behviour (a `number|undefined` can indeed contain a `string`)?

Why does the code compile with index based iteration but fails to compile using `foreach`?

What is the best practice in this situation to avoid similar unexpected type violation?

Comment: There's probably a canonical original question on this (I don't have a link for it). Basically: TypeScript's flow analysis is limited in pragmatic ways, and doesn't see side-effects inside callback closures that reach out and set local variables. It's just a pragmatic limitation of the compiler to keep it from being too slow.

Comment: If you'd used `for-of`, TypeScript would have caught it ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoD8lw)), but I'm assuming `forEach` in your example was just a stand-in for some other callback.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. So basically it's indeed the expected behavior and we should just keep in mind with using callbacks.

Comment: Yes, that's right. :-)